# Unable to get the expected output from a forloop

Tags: node.js

I've a small node.js code that is not working as expected.

There is a for-loop in my code and at the end of for-loop, I'm trying to print the result, but the output that I'm expecting is not matching the output that I'm getting. please let me know on how can I fix it.

**Here is my code:**

```
var ttall = "";
var ttall_assists = "";
var total="";
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ttall += 'AAA' + i;
    ttall_assists += 'BBB' + i + '\n';
    total+=`${ttall} ${ttall_assists}`;
}
console.log(`${total}`);
```

**Expected output is:**

AAA0
BBB0

AAA1
BBB1

AAA2
BBB2

**Currently the output that I get is:**

AAA0 BBB0

AAA0AAA1 BBB0

BBB1

AAA0AAA1AAA2 BBB0

BBB1

BBB2

Comment: Just remove += to be = for variables ttall and ttall_assists . You concatenate strings that's why you got so much data

Comment: It probably best to just do the following in the loop: `console.log(\`AAA${i} BBB${i}\`);`, there is no reason to be creating all those extra variables nor tracking the result in a buffer. All of those extra operations are creating unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong a little bit.

Using '+=' the next value is added with the previous value.
You should use like this

```
ttall = 'AAA' + i;
ttall_assists = 'BBB' + i + '\n';
```

Try this and most hopefully you will get the right result

Answer (score 0):

you dont need to concatinate the results

```js
var ttall = "";
var ttall_assists = "";
var total="";
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ttall = 'AAA' + i;
    ttall_assists = 'BBB' + i + '\n';
    total+=`${ttall} ${ttall_assists}`;
}
console.log(`${total}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

can you please try like this. I think you will get the expected output

```
var ttall = "";
var ttall_assists = "";
var total="";
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    ttall = 'AAA' + i;
    ttall_assists = 'BBB' + i + '\n';
    total+=`${ttall} ${ttall_assists}`;
}
console.log(`${total}`);
```